# Windows+Shift+S cannot paste image, have to open snip & sketch first and click on copy before I can paste

Tags: windows, screenshot, snipping, snipping-tool

I want to directly just be able to paste my screenshot after using Windows+Shift+S, I used to be able to do paste immediately but I do not know what have caused this issue.

After using Windows+Shift+S, I would have to open the snip and sketch tool and press the copy button to be able to paste it.
[Have to open the Snip & Sketch Tool and click the copy button first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnFBC.png)

Comment: Where do you want to paste your screen shot?  Ctrl+V is the keyboard shortcut to paste what's in the clipboard.  Alternatively, you can right click the pointing device and select 'paste' where you want to paste the image, assuming the destination app supports image pasting from the clipboard.

Comment: I would just paste it in word but it the paste is grayed out. I would have to open the snip and sketch app then click the copy before I can paste it. It wasn't like this before, I don't know what caused it but I didn't change any settings before.

Comment: I tried with Windows 10 and Word 2010 and nothing has prevented me from pasting the snip directly in Word.  Perhaps try another app to paste in to see if the problem is with Word or with Snip and Sketch?  I can't seem to reproduce your issue.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: I mean I also use other word editors such as one note and Google docs. I tried uninstalling the Snip and Sketch but I am not able to paste after using Windows+Shift+S

Comment: The Windows+Shift+S keyboard shortcut is part of Snip and Sketch.  The executable must be running in the background in order to function.  Did you lose the direct paste functionality before or after you attempted to uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (from Martmcd):

- go to settings -> apps -> apps & features
- click on snip & Sketch
- click advanced options
- click the reset button

try snip & Sketch again.